# Spring Boot Security Oauth2 allow specific paths unauthenticated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got up and running with various tutorials from Spring Boot to use Oauth2 and secure all endpoints.

I want to selectively filter endpoints.
For example all endpoints with `/dummy/**` should be authenticated and all other endpoints should be permitAll. I seem to be missing something over here, since regardless of what I put inside the `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` method, all my endpoints are secure.

Here is my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10));
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/dummy/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }
}
```

Here is my resource

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dummy")
public class DummyController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "Dummy";
    }
}
```

Here is AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1 * 60 * 60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6 * 60 * 60;
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "ClientId";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "secret";
    private static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    private static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    private static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .autoApprove(true)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

I've been stuck for days on end. I'm sure that it's probably something small.